# Saving plain text to RichText

Tags: c#, winforms, richtextbox

I'm a little confused with the following code. I'm taking plain text stored in a database and supplying it to the Text portion of a RichTextBox control then saving it to a file.

The first file is always blank even though it does contain data.

```
RichTextBox test = new RichTextBox();
for(int i = 0; i < dt.Rows.Count; i++)
{
     test.Text = dt.Rows[i][1].ToString();
     string FILE_NAME = Path.Combine(path, dt.Rows[i][0].ToString() + ".rtf");
     test.SaveFile(FILE_NAME, RichTextBoxStreamType.RichText);
     test.Clear();
}
```

Now currently for a work around even though it's ugly I did the following and it does write the first entry to a file correctly

```
bool run_once = true;
RichTextBox test = new RichTextBox();
for(int i = 0; i < dt.Rows.Count; i++)
{
     test.Text = dt.Rows[i][1].ToString();
     string FILE_NAME = Path.Combine(path, dt.Rows[i][0].ToString() + ".rtf");
     test.SaveFile(FILE_NAME, RichTextBoxStreamType.RichText);
     test.Clear();

     if (run_once)
     {
          File.Delete(FILE_NAME);
          run_once = false;
          i--;
     }
}
```

Could someone shed some light here?

Comment: This may help: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10725438/converting-txt-to-rtf

Comment: Using the code I have formats plain text into rtf formatting. That works but the above loop always writes the first file with no data at all. When I delete it in the work around and run that entry through again it writes the file correctly.

Comment: If you want to use the RichTextBox, LarsTech has a solution below.  Since you don't really need an actual control, I think a method that just converts to rtf may be faster.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Interesting.  I "think" it might be a bug.  This was my work-around:

```
using (RichTextBox test = new RichTextBox()) {
  for (int i = 0; i < dt.Rows.Count; i++) {
    test.SelectAll();
    test.Text = dt.Rows[i][1].ToString();
    string FILE_NAME = Path.Combine(path, dt.Rows[i][0].ToString() + ".rtf");
    test.SaveFile(FILE_NAME, RichTextBoxStreamType.RichText);
    test.Clear();
  }
}
```

The `SelectAll()` was needed to make the bug go away.  Not sure why.